# C# change page/screen?

Tags: c#, forms, screen

How do you change page/screen display in c# windows forms without using Close(); and Show(); ?

Close(); and Show(); makes the screen blink and I want it to be fluent. Can I use the menustrip to change screen ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new window at exactly the same size and position as the original, and then do a ShowModal on it. When the new window closes, though, you will be back to the original window.

You can make it the same form, but display the controls of each window in different tab pages of a TabControl. I'm not sure offhand how to hide the Tabs which allow the user to change TabPage but I think it can be done; or it might be a good thing to have them there, depending on your requirements.

You can do the Show as you are doing currently, but don't do the Close() of the original form. Instead, when the original form creates the new one, it should subscribe to an event (Activated? or create a special one fired by the new window when it's finished displaying itself) and when it receives that event it calls Close() on itself.

There's three possible ways.